# FOR loop to make table and 12 cells then new line

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I want this for loop to echo the table, make 12 cells and echo a year in each and make a new line

```
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr>";
for ($Year; $Year <= 2013; $Year++) {
    for ($i=0; $i <= 13; $i++) {

        if ($i==13) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";   
        }
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>$Year</td>";
    ++$Year;
    ++$i;
}
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

this is what im getting and what i need
[image: my output]

[image: what i need]

Comment: What is the first year?

Comment: You're double incrementing, you only need to run `$Year++;` in the for statement, not as well as in the code. But merely changing this will not entirely fix your code.

Comment: 1912 it is set in the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this simple piece of code?

```
echo "<table><tr>";

for($year = 1912; $year <= date('Y'); $year++)
{
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>{$year}</td>";
    if($year % 12 == 3) echo '</tr><tr>';
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Not really smart one, can be upgraded to better handle different starting values etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `mod` instead of the extra `for` loop:

```
$Year = 1912;
$EndYear = 2013;
$i = 1;

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

while ($Year <= $EndYear) {
    if (($i % 13) == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";   
        $i = 1;
    }
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>$Year</td>";
    ++$i;
    ++$Year;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Other technique using some PHP-Fu:

```
$start = 1912;
$end = 2013;
$array = range($start, $end);
$array_chunks = array_chunk($array, 12);
$table = '<table>';
foreach($array_chunks as $chunk){
    $table .= '<tr><td>'. implode('</td><td>', $chunk) .'</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

If you want to troll, use a "for-loop" like this:

```
$start = 1912;
$end = 2013;
$array = range($start, $end);
$array_chunks = array_chunk($array, 12);
$table = '<table>';
$c = count($array_chunks);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $table .= '<tr><td>'. implode('</td><td>', $array_chunks[$i]) .'</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr>";
$i = 0;
for ($year= 1912; $year <= 2013; $year++) {
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>$year</td>";
    if(++$i == 12) {
        echo '</tr><tr>'; 
        $i=0;
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```